# Sharepoint Link Remove Upload Function

Tags: permissions

I have shared a folder with my classmates. I have shared an edit link and I have tested it myself (after having logged out), and I noticed this:

[image: SamplePic]
I do not want to give my users upload permissions. I also do not want to modify the link as this would be rather inconvenient; I have already given the link to a number of classmates. How may I remove the upload permissions to any guest contributor?